# Local Kudu post-recieve pull not working

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive, kudu

I have a Kudu project hosted locally on a server. I'm trying to modify the post-receive hook to cd into another directory and then perform a git pull. In the directory I'm switching to I have the repository set up with the correct remote but I receive

```
remote: .............................................................fatal: prot
ocol error: bad line length character: <!DO
ferror: error in sideband demultiplexer
atal: write error: Invalid argument
```

Is there something I need to change or some other way I could update this other site with the latest push into my repository?

Comment: I've moved on to using Bonobo. Works much better for exactly what I'm trying to do. I guess this would be a better solution if we were actually deploying the website we were pushing to but that's not the case.

Comment: As an addition to using Bonobo I also had to point Bonobo to my local installed instance of git for windows in the web config. The version that came bundled with Bonobo was not able to run my script.